# git log and show on a bare repo

Tags: git

I created a bare repository on a file-server in my local network at home.
After this i pushed a branch of an existing repository from my desktop-pc to this new remote repository.

Pushing worked perfectly and it seems, that all data arrived (a "git branch -va" gives me the correct data). 
But i cannot use git log or git show on the bare repository.
i get an:

`fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

or simply no output

is this normal for bare repositories? Is there another possibility to visualize everything?

Edit:
The fatal error is solved now, but i receive no output from "git log" or "git log unstable". Same command on the desktop-pc works perfectly

Comment: Try git update-ref HEAD branch-name

Comment: @William: You want `git symbolic-ref HEAD branch-name`. Yours will make `HEAD` a normal ref.

Comment: You will see a different error message with Git 2.6+ (Q3/Q4 2015): see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370881/6309).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, this is normal for new bare (and non-bare) repositories.

#### Explanation

`HEAD` is what Git calls a *symbolic reference*—a reference to another reference.

In non-bare repositories, `HEAD` normally indicates which branch is currently checked out.  A new commit will cause the branch named by `HEAD` to be advanced to refer to the new commit.  When `HEAD` refers to a commit object directly instead of a branch, it's considered to be *detached*, meaning further commits will not cause a branch reference to be advanced to refer to the new commits (dangerous because checking out a different commit or branch will render the new commits unreachable by any existing reference, making them hard to find and subject to garbage collection).

In bare repositories, `HEAD` indicates the repository's default branch, so that in a clone of the repository `git checkout origin` is equivalent to `git checkout origin/master` if `master` is the default branch (see `git help rev-parse` for details).

When Git initializes a new repository, it initializes `HEAD` to refer to `refs/heads/master` (in other words, `HEAD` points to the `master` branch by default).  However, it does not create a branch named `master` because there are no commits in the repository for `master` to point to yet.

So until you either create a `master` branch or change `HEAD` to point to a branch that does exist, you'll get that error when you run a command that looks at `HEAD` (such as `git log` or `git show` without any arguments).

You can still use commands that don't examine `HEAD`.  For example:

```
git log some_branch_that_exists
```

#### Fix

To get rid of the error message, you can do one of the following:

- Change `HEAD` to point to a branch that does exist:

  ```
  git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/some_other_branch
  ```
- Push a new `master` branch into the repository from somewhere else
- Create a new `master` branch locally:

  ```
  git branch master some_existing_commit
  ```

#### Visualization

To visualize everything in the repository, I use something like this:

```
git log --graph --oneline --date-order --decorate --color --all
```

Note that the above command will work even if `HEAD` is pointing to a non-existent branch.

Comment: You can also mention that `git log branchname` and `git show branchname` will work

Comment: @RichardHansen that last line just took my understanding to a whole new level. Very helpful! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this message will change with Git 2.6 (Q3/Q4 2015)

See [commit ce11360](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce113604672fed9b429b1c162b1005794fff6a17) (29 Aug 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 699a0f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/699a0f3748474fce7b688212c3f9ab25d7b750f5), 02 Sep 2015)</sup>

Finally, that message will be more meaningful:

> ## `log`: diagnose empty `HEAD` more clearly
>
> If you init or clone an empty repository, the initial message from running "`git log`" is not very friendly:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/peff/foo/.git/
$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

> Let's detect this situation and write a more friendly message:

```
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

> We also detect the case that 'HEAD' points to a broken ref; this should be even less common, but is easy to see.
>   Note that we do not diagnose all possible cases. We rely on `resolve_ref`, which means we do not get information about complex cases. E.g., "`--default master`" would use `dwim_ref` to find "`refs/heads/master`", but we notice only that "`master`" does not exist.
>   Similarly, a complex sha1 expression like "`--default HEAD^2`" will not resolve as a ref.
>
> But that's OK. We fall back to a generic error message in those cases, and they are unlikely to be used anyway.
>   Catching an empty or broken "HEAD" improves the common case, and the other cases are not regressed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I first pushed to the repo a non-master branch.

To solve the problem, I just had to push master to the repo, and that's it !