# git clone gets gh-pages, I want it to clone master (from Github)

Tags: git, github, github-pages

One day I couldn't remember where my main working directory for my folder was, so I just decided to clone the project from the "git@github.com:" address that's on the github web page.

I didn't know what I was doing that day, and I created a bunch of stuff after that in the directory.  Then I did git add, git clone, and git push, (I forget how).  But now I have this branch called 'gh-pages' on the github site.  I really wish I didn't have that branch, but I do.

Today I found my original directory and I created some stuff in it today, and did some 'add' and some 'push'.  It went to the master 'branch' (which I expected, because I kinda gave up hope on the other weird branch).  But my problem is now this:

When my users (I tried this on another machine myself) do a git clone by using the address that github gives me on the main page of my project), they for some weird reason end up with the code from the 'gh-pages' branch.

Q1: How do I have them do a git clone so that they can get the stuff that I worked on today (which is in the master branch).
Q2: how do I remove the 'gh-pages' branch from the github site?  I decided to abandon it.  If you have a better suggestion, I'm receptive to that too.
Q3: Bonus points if you can tell me what I should have done earlier on, once I realized I have two places on my pc that has code for two separate branches in my project on github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1: `git clone http://remote.url/repo.git -b master`
Q2: `git push origin :gh-pages`, assuming `origin` is the remote you want to work on.

BTW, git comes with pretty good documentation. It can be accessed with

```
$ git help command
```

e.g.

```
$ git help clone
```

Answer (score 1):

### Q1: Changing Default Branch to `master`

Based on your description, it sounds like you have your default branch set to `gh-pages` instead of `master`.  To fix, log in to GitHub, click on your repository, click on the Admin button, and change Default Branch to `master`.

What this does is alter the `HEAD` symbolic reference in your GitHub repository to point to `refs/heads/master` instead of `refs/heads/gh-pages`.  When cloning a repository, Git looks at the remote repository's `HEAD` reference and uses that as the default branch to check out.  See my [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311945/712605) for more details.  Normally `HEAD` points to `refs/heads/master` on new bare repositories, but Git (and GitHub) allows you to change it.

### Q2: Delete the `gh-pages` branch

The `gh-pages` branch is a special branch GitHub uses for uploading content to [project pages](http://help.github.com/pages/).

To delete your `gh-pages` from your GitHub repository:

```
git push git@github.com:username/repo.git :gh-pages
```

or:

```
git push --delete git@github.com:username/repo.git gh-pages
```

Note that the above commands will only delete the `gh-pages` branch from your GitHub repository -- it won't delete the `gh-pages` branch from your local repository.  To delete the local `gh-pages` branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D gh-pages
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Q3:**

If I understood correctly, you have the same repo cloned twice in two separate folders, and each clone has a different branch with some usable code.

I think you have to choose the clone you want to keep then create a new branch with the same name of the other's clone branch. The following command will create a new branch and automatically checkout to it.

```
git checkout -b <other-branch-name>
```

Assuming that the other branch is already pushed on Github, you just pull it to the branch you want to keep.

```
git pull --rebase origin <other-branch-name>
```

If you haven't already pushed the other branch, publish it to the server and upload it.

```
git push origin <other-branch-name>
```

Alternatively, you can do a straight from the source to the destination branch, but I don't know how well this works. ***Disclaimer***, never tried it myself on production mode, but I know it's correct and it should work.

```
git push origin <other-branch-name>:<current-branch>
```