# fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git

I'm using GIT as my source control system. We have it installed on one of our Linux boxes. Tortoise GIT is my windows client.

This morning I checked in some changes, and tagged the code. I then did a push of my local repository to the remote repository.

When I go to my repository on the unix box and type in `git log` I get:

```
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

But when I do a `show log` using my windows `tortoiseGit` client the history comes up nicely as per below...

```
---
SHA-1: f879573ba3d8e62089b8c673257c928779f71692

Initial drop of code

---
master origin/master oms-phase4-v1.0.0
SHA-1: 56176dbe45e6175b18c9f44533828806c63142ab

OMS Phase 4 - Added OMS Cust. Order No. to EDI Purchase Order Header screens

Tag Info

object 56176dbe45e6175b18c9f44533828806c63142ab
type commit
tag oms-phase4-v1.0.0
tagger Richard Riviere <richard.riviere@myer.com.au> 1364338495 +1100

---
SHA-1: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Working dir changes
0 files changed

---
```

The code has definitely been pushed to the remote repository. I've been able to check by cloning the repository into a different directory.

Does anyone know why I am receiving the `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`?

p.s. It is a bare repository however I have created other bare repositories which have not had this problem.

Comment: Do you have a git remote?

Comment: Possibly related: [Git tracking entire home directory. Get error - fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036754/git-tracking-entire-home-directory-get-error-fatal-bad-default-revision-hea).

Comment: Possibly related: [git log and show on a bare repo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6214711/456814).

Comment: I got this error one time when I forgot to navigate to the repo first.

Comment: Note: Git 2.6 (Q3/Q4 2015) will provide a more meaningful message. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370516/6309)

Comment: A note for others bumping into this question after doing something silly, like me. I wasted a lot of time after doing a fresh clone of a new repository. I was running the git log command in the directory where I had taken the clone. Actually, I should have cd'ed to the directory which appeared there after cloning.

Comment: This is the second time git corrupts me a repository after I turn off the computer. It never happened with mercurial, it sucks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your repo is yours, what goes on in it is entirely your business until you push or (allow a) fetch or clone. When you deleted your windows repo -- that folder didn't represent your local repo, it was your actual local repo, you deleted everything done in it that was never pushed, fetched or cloned.

***edit:***  Ah, okay, I think I see what's going on here: you pushed to your linux repo but it's not bare and you never worked in it.

Instead of `git log`, do `git log --all`.  Or `git checkout`*`some-branch-name`.*

Then try cloning the repo locally, on your linux box; I bet it works. What are you using to serve your repo on linux?  Try cd'ing into its .git directory and `git daemon --base-path=. --export-all`, if that just sits there then go to your windows box and try `git clone git://your.linux.box.ip`, if the daemon complains it can't bind add `--port=54345` to the daemon invoke and `:54345` to the clone url.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I did do a push to the remote repository. I know that the push was successful because I can see the changes in GitWeb. Hence I don't think what you have said above is right.

Comment: So based on the previous comment, there is definitely code in my remote repo. but for some reason Git is not letting me clone it and instead gives me that error. Does that sound right? How can I fix it?

Comment: Glad to hear you had pushed.  Given that there weren't too many possibilities, I reproduced your `git log` behavior symptoms by pushing into a `git init`ed repo and trying to run the log.

Comment: whatever has happened it looks like I have corrupted my repository. I've been following a guide on how to try and recover my repository (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery). However a lot of the commands listed don't work for me and just error out. I think it might be quicker just to start again with this repository. It's funny, GitWeb isn't having issues. It still lists the code etc. I wonder why

Comment: So I started from scratch yesterday. I checked in my code again and tagged some changes. I still get fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' when i try to issue "git log" from unix. But when I use tortoiseGit in windows and do a "show log", the log looks nice and it shows all my history. I'm very confused about this error. Any ideas? I will change my question to reflect what i have just tried

Comment: Yes, try what I suggested in my edit.  You could also try setting up a bare repo and pushing to that (from windows or linux, it won't matter, `git push git://u/r/l '*:*'` to it so running log there doesn't have it expecting a more fully initialized worktree.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The repo's I am using are always bare. As per my modified question I can definitely clone the repository from my windows box. I just tried git log --all, i get the same error.

Comment: What's `git ls-remote origin` say from your windows repo, substituting  whatever it calls the linux repo giving us fits for "origin"?

Comment: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: You can `git push origin` but not `git ls-remote origin`?

Comment: So from my tortoise Git client I can definitely push changes remotely (which I assume is a GIT PUSH origin?). What would be the equivalent of a ls-remote origin in tortoise git?

Answer (score 60):

just do an initial commit and the error will go away:

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me

Comment: Thanks for your great answer (-:

It matches to the topic and was an easy solution for my problem after creating a repository.

Comment: Worked for me.  The error that lead to this seems to have been the need to run git config --global user.email and git config --global user.name

Answer (score 41):

This happens to me when the branch I'm working in gets deleted from the repository, but the workspace I'm in is not updated. (We have a tool that lets you create multiple git "workspaces" from the same repository using simlinks.)

If `git branch` does not mark any branch as current, try doing

```
git reset --hard <<some branch>>
```

I tried a number of approaches until I worked this one out.

Comment: This just did it for me :)

Comment: I renamed the branch I was on and got the "bad default revision" error. This fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Not committed yet?

It is a orphan branch if it has no commit.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. See the answer I provided to the response below. I am quite sure that I did do a push.

Answer (score 7):

Note: Git 2.6 (Q3/Q4 2015) will *finally* provide a more meaningful error message.

See [commit ce11360](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce113604672fed9b429b1c162b1005794fff6a17) (29 Aug 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 699a0f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/699a0f3748474fce7b688212c3f9ab25d7b750f5), 02 Sep 2015)</sup>

> ## `log`: diagnose empty `HEAD` more clearly
>
> If you init or clone an empty repository, the initial message from running "`git log`" is not very friendly:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/peff/foo/.git/
$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

> Let's detect this situation and write a more friendly message:

```
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

> We also detect the case that 'HEAD' points to a broken ref; this should be even less common, but is easy to see.
>   Note that we do not diagnose all possible cases. We rely on `resolve_ref`, which means we do not get information about complex cases. E.g., "`--default master`" would use `dwim_ref` to find "`refs/heads/master`", but we notice only that "`master`" does not exist.
>   Similarly, a complex sha1 expression like "`--default HEAD^2`" will not resolve as a ref.
>
> But that's OK. We fall back to a generic error message in those cases, and they are unlikely to be used anyway.
>   Catching an empty or broken "HEAD" improves the common case, and the other cases are not regressed.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure branch "master" exists! It's not just a name apparently.

I got this error after creating a blank bare repo, pushing a branch named "dev" to it, and trying to use git log in the bare repo. Interestingly, git branch knows that dev is the only branch existing (so I think this is a git bug).

Solution: I repeated the procedure, this time having renamed "dev" to "master" on the working repo before pushing to the bare repo. Success!

Comment: This happened to me after `scp`'ing the branch over.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to occur when `.git/HEAD` refers to a branch which does not exist. I ran into this error in a repo that had nothing in `.git/refs/heads`. I have no idea how the repo got into that state, I inherited from someone that left the company.

Comment: Same thing happened to me except the file got damaged in BSOD. I just replaced it by sha-1 hash of the current head and everything seems to be in order now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is OP's problem, but if you're like me, you ran into this error while you were trying to play around with git plumbing commands (`update-index` & `cat-file`) ***without ever actually committing anything*** in the first place. So try committing something (`git commit -am 'First commit'`) and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and couldn't solve it.

Then I noticed 3 extra files in one of my directories.

The files were named:

```
config, HEAD, description
```

I deleted the files, and the error didn't appear.

`config` contained:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
```

`HEAD` contained:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

`description` contained:

```
Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.
```

Comment: It's a pretty bad idea to remove files automatically generated by git. You're supposed to be able to fix a problem only through commands.