# Why are all my files being tracked by git

Tags: git

I am learning React/Redux and started a new app with create-react-app . The problem I am having is that when i check git status it shows every file from the desktop as tracked and ready to be added then committed. Obviously this is not what I want but i'm not sure why this is happening and/or how to stop it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git tracking entire home directory. Get error - fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036754/git-tracking-entire-home-directory-get-error-fatal-bad-default-revision-hea)

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you may have the .git file in root directory.

- remove .git file // command rm -rf .git
- cd into your project root folder // conmand cd project
- Iniciate git //command git init
- add repository url where you want to push
  // command git remote add origin ‘your repo url’
- now check status it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reset HEAD` to unstage all staged changes without undoing the changes in your working tree. After that, `git status` should show only unstaged changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply initializing the repo from the command line. I'd been banging my head against that wall for about a year and may have found the solution. The process was, create-react-app 'appname', then cd into the app name directory, then git init once inside the directory. I then created a new repo on github and chose the appropriate option. I think it was push existing repo from command line. Anyway, maybe this will help someone else one day.