# Re-initialize a bare git repository

Tags: git

Today a big problem happen to our bare git repository.
For some reasons unknown it seems that it has been re-initialized as a standard (not bare) git repo.

The strange thing is that I can still pull/push to it from Netbeans IDE but if I try the same thing from command line I obtain this error:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Anyway the files are all there, the folder branches, hooks, refs and the the others.

If I try to run `git branch` it return me nothing, if I try to run `git show` it returns me this error:

```
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

I opened the config file with `git config -e` and the bare options was set to false. I tried to set it to true manually with no luck, so I tried with `git init --bare` and it's still not working.

Is there a way to let git be aware of all the data that's still there? If not what's the best strategy to recover the bare repo?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[GIT --> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15628720/6309)", it can happen if a branch (like master) get deleted on the server, even though it is not in your local repo.

If the bare repo is really in a strange state, it is best to:

- create a new bare repo
- add that new bare repo url as a remote in your local repo (`git remote add`)
- [push from your local repo everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382703/6309)  (`git push --all` + `git push --tags`)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did a quick recovery as you suggested and everything is working fine now, thank you again! :D