# bad default revision 'HEAD' when my directory has been moved

Tags: git, corrupt, git-log

I know that there are different variations of this questions asked, but I couldn't find one that pertains to my issue I am having....

I initialized my git repo under my `~/Documents/git_project`.

I later moved the git_project folder to the `~/Dropbox` directory.

After it was moved, I got the following error bad default revision 'HEAD' when I tried doing a `git log`.

I then moved it back to the `~/Documents/` folder to see if it would fix the issue, and I still get the same message.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: That is probably why I have been advising *against* using Git repo in a DropBox folder for years now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569980/6309

Comment: Note: the error message will change with git 2.6: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370516/6309

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the post. I fixed the issue. I never did a commit to begin with. It had nothing to do with moving the directory.