# tried to push to GitHub, now getting 'fatal: bad default revision'

Tags: git, bash, github

I created a local repository for a C# project, and I've made a lot of commits to it over the past few days.

This evening I opened Git Bash so I could push the repo to Github for the first time.  I've already created an empty repo in Github for this purpose.

I entered:

```
git push origin master
```

I was then prompted to enter my Github username and password.  After that, I got this message:

```
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/master.
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git'
```

I then ran `git status`, and under `Changes to be committed:` it showed all the tracked files as new files.

I ran `git log` and got this error:

```
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

UPDATE: I tried committing and got this message:

```
error: unable to resolve reference HEAD: No such file or directory
fatal: cannot lock HEAD ref
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not have done any commit in your local repo.
That would explain why HEAD refers to a "bad revision".

Add, **[git commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)**, and then push.

Make sure to use git 2.6+ ([even on Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)): the error message should be more explicit now.
See "[`fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370516/6309)"

> Let's detect this situation and write a more friendly message:

```
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

As the [OP sigil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619177/sigil) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428732/tried-to-push-to-github-now-getting-fatal-bad-default-revision/33429263#comment54647894_33429263), it is easier to

- "deleted the existing repo, ran git init, and committed successfully".
  That is delete the .git folder first.
  But in order to push, a `git remote add origin https://url/to/remote/repo` is required, before a `git push -u origin master`.
- or clone the remote repo again, copy the files in the new local repo, add, commit and push.
  This is even easier, because the remote '`origin`' is already set, and `master` is already linked to `origin/master`, so a simple `git push` is enough.
  (See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more)

Comment: All my commits have been to the local repo, so there are many folders in the `.git/objects` folder.  I am worried that if I add and commit, I will lose all the commits that I already made.

Comment: also, please see my update to the question, I cannot commit to this repo now.

Comment: OK. What git version are you using? On which OS?

Comment: git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1 on Windows 7.  At this point I just decided that it was more important to just get my current files under source control, so i deleted the existing repo, ran git init, and committed successfully.

Comment: Good workaround. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @sigil I have aded another workaround in the answer.