# git difftool gives error

Tags: git, difftool

I would like to diff a particular file between 2 branches. I saw there is a difftool. But I tried and I'm not getting succeeded. I have a file called abc.cpp and 2 remote branches say May_Version and June_Version and my file is in the folder /xyz/tools. I tried like

```
git difftool origin/May_Version:xyz/tools/abc.cpp -- June_Version:xyz/tools/abc.cpp
```

with the above command it gives the following error

> fatal: bad revision 'May_Version:xyz/tools/abc.cpp'

I tried

```
origin/May_Version:xyz/tools/abc.cpp June_Version:xyz/tools/abc.cpp
```

> fatal: Path 'xyz/tools/abc/cpp' does not exist in May_Version.

Can someone tell me correct syntax?

Comment: Was it `abc/cpp` or `abc.cpp`?

Comment: The file name is abc.cpp

Comment: You mis-used command options, try `git difftool origin/May_Version June_Version -- xyz/tools/abc.cpp`, please make sure your $PWD is the parent folder of xyz.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the syntax

```
git difftool {local branch} {remote branch} [*optional* filename]
```

e.g. :

```
git difftool June_Version origin/May_Version
```

or if just diffing the specific file

```
git difftool June_Version origin/May_Version xyz/tools/abc.cpp
```

Comment: I tried 
git difftool June_Version origin/May_Version xyz/tools/abc.cpp and it says fatal:ambiguous argument xyz/tools/abc.cpp: unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use -- to separate paths from revisions, like this:

Comment: if I use -- to separate the paths, it does not do any thing.

Comment: It might be an issue with the currently checked out branch.  You may want to check If git branch marks a current branch any branch as current with an asterisk.  If not, you can try doing a reset on the branch

git reset --hard <<some branch>>

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628720/fatal-bad-default-revision-head

Answer (score 0):

Do it locally within your repo. No need for **origin/**.

```
git difftool --dir-diff June_Version May_Version
```