# Connect remote server to git

Tags: git

I have a remote server that has my original instance of [Omeka](https://omeka.org/):

Now, I downloaded all code in local, and created a Git Repo.

Now, as user will add content directly on my remote server, I want to commit directly remotely, and then download changes in local.

Thing is I have no git repository in my distant server.

So, I tried to copy local .git folder to distant server, but now, I get:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

How should I do it???

Comment: Does it a bare repository? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214711/git-log-and-show-on-a-bare-repo

Comment: When do you get this error? What commands can be used to replicate what you've done?

Comment: I get it when I execute git status

Comment: I m trying right now to git clone... But I got others issues...

Comment: Please elaborate `Now, I downloaded all code in local, and created a Git Repo.`. What steps did you perform?

Answer (score 1):

To serve git repo from remote, you will have to create a [bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632497/827715) on the server and serve that folder via the `https/ssh protocol`.

Then clone the remote repo via the https/ssh url onto your local server. Then you will be able to pull any commits made on the remote server.

You can find a nice tutorial [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server)

Comment: Naming the remote server «origin» would also be nice, as it is the name GIT assigns to the central servers when built the first.